# How to display 3 li elements with same width in row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to display 3 `li` elements in a row, but they must have same length.

`li` elements will be added dynamically ,because this is a React application, and when you click on **set alarm button**, form will pop-up and you are able to set new alarm. After setting an alarm, there is another component which list all of the alarms as `li` element.

My website consists of :

`.container` ,which holds everything else inside.

```
.container{
 width: 60%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top:5em;
 height: 100vh;
 text-align: center;
}
```

`.clock` - div, which is the first child of `.container`

```
.clock{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 border-radius: .5em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 2em 3em;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

**set alarm button** - this button is under `.clock div`.

```
.btn-setAlarm{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  border:0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  outline: none;
}

.btn-setAlarm:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And finally `ul` element ,in which I want all `li` elements same width, displayed inline, but maximum of 3 in one row.

```
ul{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

li{
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: .3em;
  width: 30%;
}
```

My thoughs were :

1. `display: flex` for `ul` element will make all of `li` elements display in one line
2. `flex-wrap:wrap` will break `li` elements to next line when there are too many `li` elements
3. Set `width: 30%` for `li` will secure that maximum `li` elements in one line will be 3.

But I ended up with this ,and I can't figure it out how to do that and I don't want to use floats if it's not necessary.

[image]

**EDIT : HTML structure**

```
<div className="container">
      {checkTime()}

      <div className="clock">
        <div className="time">
          <div className="column">
            <p>{time.currentDay}</p>
            <span>DAY</span>
          </div>

          <p className="dot">:</p>

          <div className="column">
            <p>{time.currentHour}</p>
            <span>HOURS</span>
          </div>

          <p className="dot">:</p>

          <div className="column">
            <p>{time.currentMinute}</p>
            <span>MINUTES</span>
          </div>

          <p className="dot">:</p>

          <div className="column">
            <p>{time.currentSecond}</p>
            <span>SECONDS</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <Alarm getInfo={getAlarm} />

      <ListAlarms alarms={time.alarms} removeAlarm={removeAlarm} />
    </div>
```

Also I'm using React Spring transitions to animate these Li elements and I've noticed that for this animation ,React spring is creating **<animated.div>**  and inside this div is **li** element placed. So I've added to this div class of **.div-li** ,to make it more formatable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you add `flex-shrink: 0`to your `li` rule, this will prevent them from getting smaller than the defined width.

EDIT/ADDITION after edit of question / posted generated HTML code:

Since the `li`s are not *direct* children of the `ul`, but there are `div.li-div` generated by React which wrap the `li`s, you need to apply the `width` setting (and probably also the other settings) to `div.li-div` instead of `li`, which are the actual flex items in this code. So that would be a rule like:

```
div.li-div {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: .3em;
  width: 30%;
}
```

If that isn't sufficient, add also `flex-shrink: 0` to avoid them from getting smaller, being flex items.

Comment: I've added it and it did not make any change.

Comment: Are the `li` elements *direct* children of the `ul`? (You should post your generated HTML code). And is the `ul` element really as wide as the button avove it?

Comment: Now I noticed that problem is ,I'm using React sping transitions to animate these li's. And when animating, these Li's are covered up in div,which is created by react spring transitions.

Comment: So you could change the CSS selector for your `li` rule to `ul > * { ... }`, i.e. addressing the direct children of the `ul` (i.e. those `div`s generated by React) - or actually `div.div-li { ...} `, after seeing the addition to your question

Answer (score 0):

set the `position` of `ul` to `relative` and `justify-content` to `space-around` this will make them get the defined width and leave space between them and also you can set the `justify-content` to `space-between` if you want to. And also is good idea to add `flex` for the `flex-shrink`, `flex-grow` and `flex-basis`

```
ul{
    position: relative;/* added */
    padding-left:0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;/* added */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

li{
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: .3em;
  width: 30%;
  flex: 0 0 0;/* added */
}
```

Comment: Copied and pasted, did not work at all.. I think Li is thinner than before. I think I can see the problem. For displaying these li's I'm using React spring transitions. and every LI which is rendered ,it is covered in another div. So maybe this is the problem

Comment: can we see the structure of your html

Comment: Edit completed. I think I've got the problem